# Правильна ли пунктуация (oднородные или неоднородные определения)?

Tags: пунктуация, прилагательные, однородные-члены

Правильна ли пунктуация в предложении:
**...кожа у девицы тонкая нежная, кровь сладкая ароматная.**

Дополнение
Полное предложение имеет такой вид:
**Протяжно зевнула, всё ещё чувствуя привкус на языке красных капель, слизнутых с когтей — кожа у девицы тонкая нежная, кровь сладкая ароматная.**
[**Оборотень**](https://ficwriter.info/proizvedeniya/5991-oboroten.html)

Comment: Исправьте название: Однородные и неоднородные определения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Кожа у девицы тонкая, нежная, кровь сладкая, ароматная.**

В данном случае прилагательные являются **именной частью сказуемого**, поэтому запятые ставятся между однородными сказуемыми.

В то же время если прилагательные  являются **определениями** и  находятся после определяемого слова, между ними тоже всегда ставится запятая, они приравниваются к однородным в любом случае.

Сравнить: **Вижу кожу  тОнкую, нЕжную.** Заметим, что такое предложение без паузы и запятой просто  "не читается", так как здесь ударением выделены именно однородные члены (определения).

[Розенталь. § 10. Однородные и неоднородные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98)

Между однородными определениями, не связанными союзами, ставится запятая:

8) если они  **стоят после определяемого существительного** (в этом положении каждое из определений непосредственно связано с существительным и имеет одинаковую смысловую самостоятельность): Я видел женщину молодую, прекрасную, добрую, интеллигентную, обаятельную (Ч.); Я буду тогда обладать истиной вечной, несомненной (Т.).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Наглядно и понятно.